# NoClassDefFoundError com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProject

Tags: java, wsdl, soapui

i'm trying to write a SoapUI Java Application. After instance a WSDLProject object i'm getting these error codes:

```
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProject
    at WSDLTest.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:27)
    at de.delicom.testosgi.Activator.start(Activator.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject cannot be found by de.xxx.testosgi_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more`
```

my code is:

```
 public Connector(String link) throws Exception{

        SoapUI sui;

        WsdlProject wsdl = new WsdlProject("https://public-ws.dpd.com/services/DepotDataService/V1_0/?wsdl");
```

i included these external JARs:

- soapui-4.0.1.0.jar
- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
- xmlbeans-xpath-2.6.0.jar

Best wishes

Comment: You add it to your buildpath or to your classpath?

Comment: i added it to my buildpath

Comment: So you have to add it also to the classpath

Comment: `com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProject` is on soapui.jar so as @Jens comments you must add the jar to the classpath `:)`... then probably you've to add a lot of jars to the classpath since soapui.jar has a lot of dependencies... probably it's better to use maven or gradle which does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

First: I think you should try to change your code, something like this:

```
    String urlWsdl = "http://yourUrlWSDL";
    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();    
    WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, urlWsdl);
    wsdl = wsdls[0];
```

Second: Try adding the following libraries (to your maven project), copying dependencies and repositories of this pom.xml:

http://pastebin.com/iqV5B7aT

Note: The pom.xml has been used for a small app that uses soap services