# WsdlProject(); cannot be cast to com.eviware.soapui.config.DefaultEndpointStrategyConfig

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

TL:DR =>  `WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();`

throws

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eviware.soapui.config.impl.EndpointStrategyConfigImpl cannot be cast to com.eviware.soapui.config.DefaultEndpointStrategyConfig`

Hello, sorry for long post, but I did really tried to solve this on my own and I couldn't.

I am learning how to use SOAP request. And for this I am using SoapUI 5.6 (Free version) and testing  the free wsdl API: http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL

From the SoapUI 5.6 I have successful sending of requests and receiving responses. But I want to do that "wit Java from IntelliJ".

My task is to use **com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.class** I have read quite a few tutorials and solved a few errors. The current error that I have though, I cannot solve. It is as follows:

`13:01:59,689 INFO  [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 1 ms 13:01:59,689 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eviware.soapui.config.impl.EndpointStrategyConfigImpl cannot be cast to com.eviware.soapui.config.DefaultEndpointStrategyConfig`

I have followed  this topic  [NoClassDefFoundError com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277896/noclassdeffounderror-com-eviware-soapui-impl-wsdl-wsdlproject)

And I have created my initial code

`String endPointUrl = "http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL"; WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject(); WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, endPointUrl); WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];`

The error is thrown when trying to create empty WsdlProject object.

From a comment in the thread above I see that I have to implement some dependancies which as 2016 were obviously accecable but not today. So I read that I have to use foreign repository which I have added to my pom.xml file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>smartbear</id>
        <name>smartbear repository</name>
        <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And I have added dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Which is now synced and I am able to import

`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*`

I am sorry but I cannot seem to solve this issue:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eviware.soapui.config.impl.EndpointStrategyConfigImpl cannot be cast to com.eviware.soapui.config.DefaultEndpointStrategyConfig`

Any idea what could cause it?

Java 1.8 and Windows 10 64b with IntelliJ community Build #IC-212.4746.92, built on July 27, 2021

here is the class https://pastebin.com/pFSTmTsr